# Robot-to-robot relative position over time?

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, cameras

I have 3 robots and I know the starts and end coordinate of each of them. For example for Robot 1 I have Xr1, Yr1 and Xr2,Yr2 coordinates pair , same for Robot2 and 3. I have lateral cameras so can obtain the visual information. I would like to get the robot-to-robot relative position over time. So I can record all Sensor data and do the localization offline . The camera update is every 0.5 seconds. And each robot covered 300 degree horizontal field of view. How can I approach this problem and any possible solution? Is the Hidden Markov Model chains would be a good approach? OR semantic Mapping can be helpful?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Macedon971, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok. Edit more infos. Is that ok now?